# iOS [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil - So Annoying

Tags: ios, mobile, breakpoints, instagram

This is driving me crazy!

I'm seeing :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x28f9012 0x271ee7e 0x28acb6a 0x28aca20 0x5866c 0x5eeee 0x154f103 0x154f42b 0x155cf80 0x1564fad 0x156589b 0x1565e93 0x1565a88 0x8628 0x2732705 0x146f2c0 0x16aba64 0x2732705 0x146f2c0 0x146f258 0x1530021 0x153057f 0x152f6e8 0x149ecef 0x149ef02 0x147cd4a 0x146e698 0x2d76df9 0x2d76ad0 0x286ebf5 0x286e962 0x289fbb6 0x289ef44 0x289ee1b 0x2d757e3 0x2d75668 0x146bffc 0x3210 0x3175)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

First break point is catching at :

```
NSMutableArray *imgArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    IMReviewView *subview = [[IMReviewView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    subview.delegate = self;
    subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:0];
    UIImage *img1 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    img1 = subview.photo.image;
    [imgArray addObject:img1]; //Breaking Here....
```

Not sure how this has suddenly started becoming an issue, i've restored back to earlier builds, tried another workstation however still seeing this error in the below code :

Any ideas? (had to trim the file hence the sudden ending)

```
@implementation IMReviewViewController {
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    //UIPageControl *pageControl;
    BOOL continueButtonDisabled;
    NSUInteger downloadedImageCount;
}

@synthesize frameImage;

@synthesize removeButton;
@synthesize caption;
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize photo = _photo;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc - IMReviewViewController");
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    //    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(removePhoto:)]) {
    //        [self.delegate removePhoto:removePhoto:self.photo];
    //    }

    for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(3.0f, 3.0f), 2.0f);

    if (self.frameImage) {
        [self.frameImage drawInRect:rect];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)setReviewImages
{
    continueButtonDisabled = YES;
    downloadedImageCount = 0;

    NSArray *reviewViews = scrollView.subviews;
    for (IMReviewView *reviewView in reviewViews) {
        [reviewView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    NSUInteger photoCount = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoCount];
    if ( nPageNum == 0 ){
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < photoCount; i++) {

            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x  = scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
            frame.origin.y  = 65;
            frame.size      = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, 327.0f);

            IMReviewView *subview = [[IMReviewView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            subview.delegate = self;
            subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:i];
            [scrollView addSubview:subview];

            scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * i, scrollView.frame.size.height);

            UILabel *headingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 20, 300, 30)];
            [self.view addSubview:headingLabel];


            headingLabel.text = @"Time To Preview!";
            headingLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            headingLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

            headingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            headingLabel.tag = 10;
            headingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            headingLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:26.0f];
            headingLabel.hidden = NO;
            headingLabel.highlighted = YES;
            headingLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            headingLabel.lineBreakMode = YES;
            headingLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        }

        //  pageControl.numberOfPages = photoCoun
    }else if( nPageNum == 1 ){

        int nVWidth, nVHeight;
        nVWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
        nVHeight = (self.view.frame.size.height - 310) / 2;

        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x  = 27.0f;
        frame.origin.y  = 65;
        frame.size      = CGSizeMake(269.5f, 253.5f);

        IMReviewView *subview = [[IMReviewView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.delegate = self;
        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:0];
        UIImage *img1 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img1 = subview.photo.image;

        NSURL *imageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"FramedBack" withExtension:@"png"];
        frameImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];

        //Header Text above print

        UILabel *headingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 20, 300, 30)];
        [self.view addSubview:headingLabel];


        headingLabel.text = @"Time To Preview!";
        headingLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headingLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

        headingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        headingLabel.tag = 10;
        headingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        headingLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:26.0f];
        headingLabel.hidden = NO;
        headingLabel.highlighted = YES;
        headingLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headingLabel.lineBreakMode = YES;
        headingLabel.numberOfLines = 0;


        //----------------
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));
        CGSize divSize = CGSizeMake(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];

        image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
        //image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];


        image = img1;
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(300, 300, divSize.width-600, divSize.height-600)];

        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        UIImageView *viewImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];
        [viewImage setFrame:frame];
        [scrollView addSubview:viewImage];

        NSURL *buottonImageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"RemoveIcon@2x" withExtension:@"png"];
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:buottonImageURL]];
        self.removeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13.0f, 50, 38.0f, 38.0f)];
        [self.removeButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.removeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [scrollView addSubview:self.removeButton];


        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    }else if( nPageNum == 2 ){
        int nVWidth, nVHeight;
        nVWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
        nVHeight = (self.view.frame.size.height - 330) / 2;

        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x  = 27.0f;
        frame.origin.y  = 65;
        frame.size      = CGSizeMake(269.5f, 253.5f);


        NSMutableArray *imgArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        IMReviewView *subview = [[IMReviewView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.delegate = self;
        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:0];
        UIImage *img1 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img1 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img1];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:1];
        UIImage *img2 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img2 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img2];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:2];
        UIImage *img3 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img3 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img3];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:3];
        UIImage *img4 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img4 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img4];

        NSURL *imageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"FramedBack" withExtension:@"png"];
        frameImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];

        //Header Text above print

        UILabel *headingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 20, 300, 30)];
        [self.view addSubview:headingLabel];


        headingLabel.text = @"Time To Preview!";
        headingLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headingLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

        headingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        headingLabel.tag = 10;
        headingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        headingLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:26.0f];
        headingLabel.hidden = NO;
        headingLabel.highlighted = YES;
        headingLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headingLabel.lineBreakMode = YES;
        headingLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        //Footer Text under print

        UILabel *footer = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 330, 226, 50)];
        [self.view addSubview:footer];

        footer.text = @"*Please note, you cannot select the layout of the images within the grid at this time.";
        footer.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        footer.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

        footer.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        footer.tag = 10;
        footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        footer.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9.0f];
        footer.hidden = NO;
        footer.highlighted = YES;
        footer.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        footer.lineBreakMode = YES;
        footer.numberOfLines = 0;

        //----------------
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));
        CGSize divSize = CGSizeMake(IMAGE_WIDTH / 2, IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2);
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];

        image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];


        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:0];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(200, 200, divSize.width-210, divSize.height-210)];

        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:1];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(divSize.width, 200, divSize.width-210, divSize.height-210)];

        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:2];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(200, divSize.height, divSize.width-210, divSize.height-210)];

        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:3];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(divSize.width, divSize.height, divSize.width-210, divSize.height-210)];

        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        UIImageView *viewImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];
        [viewImage setFrame:frame];
        [scrollView addSubview:viewImage];

        NSURL *buottonImageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"RemoveIcon@2x" withExtension:@"png"];
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:buottonImageURL]];
        self.removeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13.0f, 50, 38.0f, 38.0f)];
        [self.removeButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.removeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [scrollView addSubview:self.removeButton];


        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    }else if( nPageNum == 3 ){
        int nVWidth, nVHeight;
        nVWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
        nVHeight = (self.view.frame.size.height - 243) / 2;
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x  = 27.0f;
        frame.origin.y  = 65;
        frame.size      = CGSizeMake(269.5f, 253.5f);

        NSMutableArray *imgArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        IMReviewView *subview = [[IMReviewView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.delegate = self;
        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:0];
        UIImage *img1 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img1 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img1];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:1];
        UIImage *img2 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img2 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img2];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:2];
        UIImage *img3 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img3 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img3];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:3];
        UIImage *img4 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img4 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img4];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:4];
        UIImage *img5 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img5 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img5];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:5];
        UIImage *img6 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img6 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img6];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:6];
        UIImage *img7 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img7 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img7];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:7];
        UIImage *img8 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img8 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img8];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:8];
        UIImage *img9 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img9 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img9];

        NSURL *imageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"FramedBack" withExtension:@"png"];
        frameImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];

        //Header Text above print

        UILabel *headingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 20, 300, 30)];
        [self.view addSubview:headingLabel];


        headingLabel.text = @"Time To Preview!";
        headingLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headingLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

        headingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        headingLabel.tag = 10;
        headingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        headingLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:26.0f];
        headingLabel.hidden = NO;
        headingLabel.highlighted = YES;
        headingLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headingLabel.lineBreakMode = YES;
        headingLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        //Footer Text under print

        UILabel *footer = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 330, 226, 50)];
        [self.view addSubview:footer];

        footer.text = @"*Please note, you cannot select the layout of the images within the grid at this time.";
        footer.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        footer.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

        footer.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        footer.tag = 10;
        footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        footer.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9.0f];
        footer.hidden = NO;
        footer.highlighted = YES;
        footer.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        footer.lineBreakMode = YES;
        footer.numberOfLines = 0;

        //----------------
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));
        CGSize divSize = CGSizeMake(IMAGE_WIDTH / 3, IMAGE_HEIGHT / 3);
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];

        image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];


        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:0];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(210, 210, divSize.width-150, divSize.height-150)];

        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:1];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(divSize.width + 70, 210, divSize.width-150, divSize.height-150)];

        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:2];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(divSize.width * 2 - 70, 210, divSize.width-150, divSize.height-150)];

        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:3];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(210, divSize.height + 70, divSize.width-150, divSize.height-150)];

        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:4];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(divSize.width + 70, divSize.height + 70, divSize.width-150, divSize.height-150)];

        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:5];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(divSize.width * 2 - 70, divSize.height + 70, divSize.width-150, divSize.height-150)];

        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:6];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(210, divSize.height*2 -70, divSize.width-150, divSize.height-150)];

        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:7];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(divSize.width + 70, divSize.height*2 -70, divSize.width-150, divSize.height-150)];

        image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:8];
        image = [image resizedImage:divSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(divSize.width * 2 - 70, divSize.height*2 -70, divSize.width-150, divSize.height-150)];

        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        UIImageView *viewImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];
        [viewImage setFrame:frame];
        [scrollView addSubview:viewImage];

        NSURL *buottonImageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"RemoveIcon@2x" withExtension:@"png"];
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:buottonImageURL]];
        self.removeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13.0f, 50, 38.0f, 38.0f)];
        [self.removeButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.removeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [scrollView addSubview:self.removeButton];


        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    }else if( nPageNum == 4 ){
        int nVWidth, nVHeight;
        nVWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
        nVHeight = (self.view.frame.size.height - 243) / 2;
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x  = 27.0f;
        //        frame.origin.y  = 23.0f;
        frame.origin.y = 65;
        frame.size      = CGSizeMake(269.5f, 253.5f);

        NSMutableArray *imgArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        IMReviewView *subview = [[IMReviewView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.delegate = self;
        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:0];
        UIImage *img1 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img1 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img1];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:1];
        UIImage *img2 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img2 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img2];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:2];
        UIImage *img3 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img3 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img3];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:3];
        UIImage *img4 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img4 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img4];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:4];
        UIImage *img5 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img5 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img5];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:5];
        UIImage *img6 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img6 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img6];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:6];
        UIImage *img7 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img7 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img7];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:7];
        UIImage *img8 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img8 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img8];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:8];
        UIImage *img9 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img9 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img9];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:9];
        UIImage *img10 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img10 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img10];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:10];
        UIImage *img11 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img11 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img11];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:11];
        UIImage *img12 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img12 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img12];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:12];
        UIImage *img13 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img13 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img13];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:13];
        UIImage *img14 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img14 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img14];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:14];
        UIImage *img15 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img15 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img15];

        subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:15];
        UIImage *img16 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        img16 = subview.photo.image;
        [imgArray addObject:img16];
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the error is on the line:

```
[imgArray addObject:img1];
```

this means that `img1` is `nil`. Since you get `img1` from `subview.photo.image` this means one of three things:

1. `subview.photo.image` is `nil`.
2. `subview.photo` is `nil`.
3. `subview` is `nil`.

Since you just created `subview` then it probably isn't #3. Since you get `subview.photo` from:

```
[[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:0];
```

You should verify that this returns a non-nil value. If it is non-nil then verify the `image` property isn't `nil`.

Side note:

These two lines:

```
UIImage *img1 = [[UIImage alloc] init];
img1 = subview.photo.image;
```

create a wasted `UIImage`. Just do:

```
UIImage *img1 = subview.photo.image;
```

Comment: The strange thing is that sometimes it's fine. And others it will crash out at say IMG4.